# Razor: button click not fired correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view. I want to load it to get all information then click **Edit** or **Delete** button to do something. When click **Edit** button then I hope it goes to another view.

```
    @model Models.CountryLanguagesModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Language";
}


<div class="span4 proj-div text-center" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addLanguageModal">
    <u>Add Language</u>
    <div><br /> </div>

    <table class="table table-bordered table-dark-header table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Language Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Welcome Message</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var item in Model.CountryLanguages)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LanguageName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WelcomeMessage)</td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="editLanguage">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteLanguage">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="addLanguageModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3>Add Language</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="left">
                        <label>Language Name:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="languageName" id="languageName" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="left">
                        <label>Welcome Messagee:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="welcomeMessage" id="welcomeMessage" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button class="btn btn-gray" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addLanguageBtn">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#addLanguageBtn").on("click", function (evt) {
                var CountryId = @Model.CountryId;
                var languageName = $("#languageName").val();
                var welcomeMessage = $("#welcomeMessage").val();
                $.post("/Country/AddLanguage", { id: CountryId, languageName: languageName, welcomeMessage: welcomeMessage }, function (data) {

                    $("#languageName").val("");
                    $("#welcomeMessage").val("");
                    $("#addLanguageModal").modal('hide');
                });
            });

            $("#editLanguage").on("click", function (evt) {
                var CountryId = @Model.CountryId;
                $.post("/Country/LanguageEdit", { id: CountryId }, function () {
                });
            });

            $("deleteLanguage").on("click", function (evt) {
                var CountryId = @Model.CountryId;
                $.post("/Country/LanguageDelete", { id: CountryId }, function () {
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Now the question is when the page loaded, I found the the code reached click event script. It is strange. When I click the button, it doesn't reach the script. But it goes to the controller action method,

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LanguageEdit(MyModel model)
    {
```

I guess some stupid error to cause the onclick event not fired correctly, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT**

```
 public ActionResult LanguageEdit(int id)
    {
        var model = new CountryLanguageModel();
        model.CountryId = id;
        model.CountryLanguageQuestion = MyService.GetQuestion(x => x.CountryId == id);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please be clear with the issue? Also try to share the javascript code for edit click button.

Comment: @ssilas777, I have the script code there.

Comment: Can you check the browser console for any script errors?

Comment: I'm not clear. Does your the browser make the post request when you click edit?

Comment: @mjw, no script error. I have the action method `public ActionResult LanguageEdit(int id)
        {`. It is never reached.

Comment: Where is your `Form` ? You typically use `@Html.BeginForm` or `@Ajax.BeginForm`

Comment: SInce  you are AJAX posting through JQuery, this is where i use FireFox's network tab to see if there is a 401, 404, or 500 error when making the request.  Also, I saw your comment on mersey post.  Do you have 2 methods with same name and POST operation?  Is the version with CountryID should be `$.get` instead?  The method you have above takes a model from the post but the JavaScript code only passes the CountryID...  can you also include that version of LanguageEdit action method?

Comment: @BrianMains. There is no 401, 404 or 500 error. I use chrome debugging. Yes, I do have 2 methods with the same name `LanguageEdit` . One passed int id, the other one passed model. But I do it by this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5). In the link, the example has two methods with the same name `public ActionResult Edit(int id)` and `public ActionResult Edit(Album album)`

Comment: In this example, the Edit(int id) is a GET operation, and the Edit(Album album) is a POST operation.  That would mean, to call Edit(int id), you would use $.get or `$.ajax({ type: 'get' })`.  If that is how your code is setup, you are calling `$.post` which needs to be changed to `$.get`.

Comment: @BrianMains, same thing even changed to `$.get`. It must be something else. And like I said the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5 uses `$.post` if I read it correctly.

Comment: Could you update the post to include the signature of the LanguageEdit(int CountryID)?

Comment: @BrianMains, I updated it. Maybe I have to  put the button into `@Html.BeginForm` then it works?

Comment: There are some inconsistencies here and I'd recommend not using the jquery $.post statements to make the call; that is async, but it gets a view returned to it, which is not working as expected.  It would be better off just letting the buttons postback normally, and then look to add AJAX solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you change button to a ?

```
 <button class="btn btn-success" id="editLanguage">Edit</button>
```

to

```
<a href="/Country/LanguageEdit?id=@Model.CountryId" class="btn btn-success" />
```

Some more information

1. if you want to GET somekind of HTML use HTTPGET instead of HTTPPOST.
   Use HTTPPOST if you want to send some kind of information, that server should for example save. Use HTTPGET if you want to render some kind of view ( for example get a new view),
2. Your Action required 'MyModel model' not a id.

Comment: When you handle Edit, it needs two methods. One is with id, the other one is with model. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5

Comment: @Bigeyes ofc. but you just showed me only one action.

Why jquery does not work? because you success method does not do anything. 

 $.post("/Country/LanguageEdit", { id: CountryId }, function () {
//HERE INSERT WHAT HAVE TO HAPPEND AFTER YOU RECEIVE VIEW
                })

Comment: But why it was fired when page loaded, I didn't click the button at all.

Comment: I need more description from You to answer question :(

Answer (score 1):

Add type='button' attribute to your buttons, if not it will behave as a submit button.

Comment: With "It doesn't work" are you saying that is still submitting the data to the HTTPPost action? or are you saying that your click event is not calling the js function?

Comment: It means same thing, it still goes to HttpPost. The click event was fired when page loaded rather than click it.

Comment: I tried your code, it works as intended.

Check if you are not loading jquery twice.

Comment: Is it a typo? I think that adding type="submit" in your answer rather than type="button".

Comment: No, type='submit' will submit your form (in case you have one).
type='button' will make your button behave as a button and you will have to submit your form via ajax

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you may get this behaviour:

> why it was fired when page loaded, I didn't click the button at all.

When your javascript code not inside the button click event and instead it is inside any of the other event such document ready or page load ..etc.

So kindly check the event of javascript and surely you will get the direction to solution .

After checked ,If you ,still had the same problem. kindly show us your javascript  so that it will be useful to help you further

Thanks

Karthik